# WCF Error 401 Unauthorized only on some pcs

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf, iis-7

I have a  WinForms app that calls a WCF service hosted on IIS7. For some reason, computers attached to the client network get a 401 Unauthorized error when trying to connect to the WCF Service through the WinForms app. I have spent quite a bit of time trying to figure this out and this is what I have found out so far.

- The WinForms app receives the WCF service data on any other PC not on the client network.
- From the client network, I can browse to the WCF service through a web browser just fine.
- From the client network, I can browse to a service method and get the "Method not allowed"
  error as expected.

Also, it should be noted that the WCF service is using REST instead of SOAP.

Here is the code I use to do all the service calls:

```
            byte[] dataStream = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strParameters);
            WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(strUrl + strFunction);
            webRequest.Method = "POST";
            webRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            webRequest.ContentLength = dataStream.Length;
            Stream newStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream();

            newStream.Write(dataStream, 0, dataStream.Length);
            newStream.Close();
            WebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponse();
            Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader responseReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
            string responseString = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
```

Does anyone have any clues as to why I would be getting the 401 error only on the Client's network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to try the call via fiddler from the clients machine and validate if you can get the expected result via a POST. If this is successful I would look into how you are hosting the service in IIS. I have seen on several occasions where the issue was Anonymous or Basic Authentication was turned off which caused similar issues.

Comment: I have anonymous turned on with a user account assigned to it, but it didn't resolve the issue. Fiddler is a great idea though, I've never used it so I'll experiment with it and see if I can get some successful requests.

Comment: Turns out the client's firewall was blocking the requests. Thanks.